# IShellDispatch NameSpace-call fails, don't know why

Tags: c++, com, shell32

First time working with COM from C++, been using C# and Delphi before.

So here's the code

```
    HRESULT Result;
    Result = CoInitialize(nullptr);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(Result))
        return Result;
    IShellDispatch* API;
    Result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellDispatch, (void **)&API);
    if ((!SUCCEEDED(Result)) || (nullptr == API))
        goto Cleanup;
    VARIANT Source1, Source2, Destination, Options;
    VariantInit(&Destination);
    Destination.vt = VT_BSTR;
    Destination.bstrVal = SysAllocString(OutFile.c_str());
    Folder* PDestination;
    Result = API->NameSpace(Destination, &PDestination);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(Result))
        goto Cleanup;
    VariantInit(&Source1);
    VariantInit(&Source2);
    Source1.vt = VT_BSTR;
    Source2.vt = VT_BSTR;
    Source1.bstrVal = SysAllocString(InFile1.c_str());
    Source2.bstrVal = SysAllocString(InFile2.c_str());
    VariantInit(&Options);
    Options.vt = VT_I4;
    Options.lVal = FOF_NO_UI;
    PDestination->CopyHere(Source1, Options);
    Sleep(1000);
    PDestination->CopyHere(Source2, Options);
    Sleep(1000);
    PDestination->Release();
    API->Release();
Cleanup:
    CoUninitialize();
    return Result;
```

OutFile, InFile1 and InFile2 are of type wstring as the program is (mostly) C++. I've managed to create an empty ZIP file, that's not the issue. The issue is that I get an exception claiming that PDestination is nullptr.

If it helps, the variants themselves seems to work. Inspecting them in the debugger yields the paths I provided. I've noticed though how the NameSpace-call returns an S_FALSE. Does anyone know what I can do about that?

Using a library doesn't exactly work, it's corporate code and there's some truly draconian rules when it comes to linking external code so using the Windows API is the easiest way.

Comment: PDestination is null out of the Namespace method call? With a 0 Result value?

Comment: Yes, PDestination is NULL out of the Namespace call. However, the result is S_FALSE. Which I haven't checked assuming the SUCCEEDED macro would check that for me. Now that I know this assumption is wrong, looks like I have to replace SUCCEEDED with an explicit !=S_OK. That said, any idea why it returns S_FALSE or what I can do about it?

Comment: Null is a documented valid return value, it means that the folder does not exist.  `OutFile` does not sound like a folder name.

Comment: I was about to say the same. Although the doc says "Creates and returns a Folder object for the specified folder.", it will not create an underlying storage folder (CreateDirectory if you want a physical folder), it will just create an object of type Folder, if there's an underlying folder ...